# boost program_option case insensitive parse of a configuration file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I would like to use boost::program_options to read the options from a configuration file, allowing for a case insensitive parsing.

Consider, e.g., the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/program_options/options_description.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/parsers.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  namespace po = boost::program_options;

  ifstream inputfile("input.dat");
  po::options_description desc("");
  desc.add_options()
    ("l", po::value<unsigned int>())
    ;
  po::variables_map vm;
  po::store(po::parse_config_file(inputfile, desc), vm);
  po::notify(vm);

  if (vm.count("l"))
    cout << "l is set as " << vm["l"].as<unsigned int>() << endl;
  else
    cout << "l is not set";

  return 0;
}
```

With the following `input.dat` file

```
l=3
```

the program runs fine giving output

```
l is set as 3
```

If I change the `input.dat` as

```
L=3
```

the program terminates raising an exception

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::unknown_option> >'
  what():  unrecognised option 'L'
Aborted
```

Case-insensitive parsing is apparently possible on the command-line, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419665/boost-program-option-case-insensitive-parsing).
Is it possible to have a case-insentive parsing also for reading from a configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an option.

You can suggest features to the library maintainers.

You can eithr convert the inifile to preferred case using other tools, or add options descriptions for case complements.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. Following your advice I inserted the filtered input file into a ```stringstream``` object and passed it to ```po::parse_config_file```